# where is the data of a file sent via file-multipart stored?

Tags: rest, http, multipartform-data, multipart

When sending an image via `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` , I see this in my POST request body

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryBB26cXe41lTj0CmC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="My file.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryBB26cXe41lTj0CmC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

My file.jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryBB26cXe41lTj0CmC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileSize"

2268401
------WebKitFormBoundaryBB26cXe41lTj0CmC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileType"

image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryBB26cXe41lTj0CmC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileLastMod"

Wed Oct 04 2017 18:09:55 GMT+0200 (CEST)
------WebKitFormBoundaryBB26cXe41lTj0CmC--
```

This obviously doen't contain all the info that makes `My file.jpeg`.

So where is the actual data that makes `My file.jpeg` stored in this request ?

Answer (score 0):

The image data is clearly not there. It comes right after any headers. In your case it's `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. And it ends at the next boundary, in your case `------WebKitFormBoundaryBB26cXe41lTj0CmC`